# Should i use PubNub Storage or google datastore to store my chat data?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, pubnub

I'm wondering what is the best option to store messages from a pubnub based chat application.

Should i use the pubnub Storage addon or it's better to use the google datastore ?

Is the pubnub storage highly scalable and able to scale to millions messages ?

Is it reliable ? Are my data safely stored (No risk to get them lost ?)

What are the pros and cons about using pubnub homemade storage over google datastore ?

Thank for helping.

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub is a Realtime Data Stream Network

I would not base my decision on whether to use PubNub, or not, based on storage because [PubNub is primarily a highly scalable and reliable *realtime data stream network*](https://www.pubnub.com/products/global-data-stream-network/) - *yes, I work for PubNub, it's in my profile* ;)

And, PubNub has a [Storage add-on](https://www.pubnub.com/products/storage-and-playback/) that will persist every single message you publish (unless you indicate `do not store` in the `publish`) using a time series data store. Those messages can be retrieved using the `history` API by passing the channel and optionally a timetoken (start & end) and other optional parameters.

If you want your messages persisted in another database, like your own RDBMS or non-SQL service, then you can use PubNub BLOCKS to send published message, asynchronously, to that database to be stored. BLOCKS run inside the PubNub Network and there is much more you can do with them.

[PubNub BLOCKS goes live September 12th.](https://www.pubnub.com/products/blocks/)

Comment: Related, have you considered a storage add-on that pushes into Cloud Datastore? Feel free to contact me if you want to chat.

Comment: Dan - The target data store is completely up to the developer. Cloud Datastore would be included in that group. Our Storage doesn't need to push to a third party because the PubNub BLOCK will do it before it is even stored in PubNub's Storage.

Comment: @CraigConover Thanks for your answer. PubNub seems to be very simple to use especially for a not experimented dev like me. I collected some informations about The pubNub storage and it's seems to be a good option. My doubts were about the scalability and the reliability performances compared to the google datastore but its seems PubNub is able to manage a very high data stream. If it is the case, i see no reason to use the datastore to save my chat messages over the Pubnub storage addon. Thanks.

Comment: PubNub scales! It is why we are very successful.